# Class 'Google_Client' not found in cake php

Tags: cakephp

I am working on google login in cake PHP. And I got one error while clicking on Google sign-in button.

> "Class 'Google_Client' not found".

Can you help me how to solve this in cake PHP? I am new to CakePHP.

```
public function googlelogin(){

    App::uses('Google_Client', 'Google');
    $client = new Google_Client();
    dd($client);
    $client->setClientId(Configure::read('Google.googleClientID'));
    $client->setClientSecret(Configure::read('Google.googleClientSecret'));
    $client->setRedirectUri(Configure::read('Google.googleRedirectUrl'));
    $client->setScopes([
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        ]);
    $url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $this->redirect($url);
}
```

Version . 2.8

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: @ndm 2.8.0 version